# How to configure helper service in OATS

Tags: oracle

I've installed OATS in my system and tried the following "run cmd as Administrator and run InstallBrowserHelpers.bat"  but unable to enable helpers service

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Running direct BAT file, i would recommend run Open Script Diagnostic from OATS tool itself

Navigate to Help---->OpenScript Diagnosis Tool ]
[image: Navigate to Help---->OpenScript Diagnosis Tool]

Next Check helper Service Check box
[image]

Click Next
Tool will re-update/re-start helper service
Plus it will tell you if any more issues you have with tool .
[image]

Check this website for more tips and tricks for Oracle Application Testing Tool related
http://www.testinghive.com/category/oracle-application-testing-suite-tips/